# javascript setInterval() not working in IE8 only within this script

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I made an HTML table and wrote a script to access its cells (td's) one by one via id and change its background-color into yellow every second.

I gave the cells the IDs "1","2","3",....,"8".

here's the script :

```
var i=0;
var intervalstop=setInterval(changecolor,1000);
function changecolor()
{
    document.getElementById((i++)%9+"").style.backgroundColor="yellow" ;
    document.getElementById((i-2)%9+"").style.backgroundColor="white" ;
}
```

this worked fine on Firefox and chrome but worked only once on IE8 without repeating (only one cell is changed into yellow)

I wanted to make sure that IE8 dosen't has problems with setinterval generally 
and modified the script to just alert("hi") every second and it worked fine on IE8
so what's the conflict between the above code and IE8 ?!
Thanks :)

Comment: HTML4 doesn't allow numeric IDs, maybe IE8 doesn't support them.

Comment: Maybe its your ids that start with a number.

Comment: What happens if you just call `changecolor()` directly, not from `setInterval()`?

Comment: Do you have a cell with ID "0"? The second time the function runs, it will try to find that cell.